# How to adjust background color on mobile view (specific case)

Tags: css, background-color

As you can see on the 2 pictures, when I load my page in mobile view, the blue background color I applied behind my text is not good looking because not properly centered anymore.
I'm looking for a way to keep this background color but spaced properly around the text.
Should I use a specific trick ?

[Desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21aP1.png)

[Mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjrDF.png)

Edit : here's the code. But there is nothing tricky here, just background color.

// HTML //

```
<div class="banner">
<p>Suggestions de présentation</p>
</div>
```

// CSS //

```
.banner {
 background-color: #0452A6;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 7px 10px;
 }
```

I want to keep it as such on mobile view, but with blue background color centered correctly.

Comment: You need to show your code please.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see the code it's difficult to give an accurate answer. If you're just looking to keep the text on a single line, you could try white-space:pre.

W3 schools has a great version to show you what it can do.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text_white-space

Code is as follows:

```
//html
<p> This is my text</p>
//css
p { white-space: pre;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I'm not trying to keep the text on a single line, I'm trying to center the blue background color evenly on mobile view